# Would a question about whether it is possible to play a note on the flute at a certain dynamic and tempo be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

Before I ask the question, sorry that the title is so long. If somebody could shorten it while still getting across what I am asking about, that would be nice. On to the question itself.

So, I have this question that might possibly be on topic for the main site. I have already asked it in the chat just in case it isn't on topic for the main site. The question has to do with whether or not a specific passage I composed for the flute in a duet piece of mine is possible to play at fortissimo given the Presto tempo or whether it is too low and I should raise it up an octave.

This question clearly has to do with [composition](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/composition) and [flute](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flute), but does it fit the guidelines for an on topic question?

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like a great fit for our site. It's a question regarding orchestration that is applicable to composers, performers, and conductors alike.

The only opinion-based aspect I can spot in the question is how one exactly defines *fortissimo*; this dynamic for me might be very different from this dynamic for you. But that strikes me as an understandable and even common level of subjectivity for SE questions.

If you really want to try and make it as objective as possible, you might choose to show us what the rest of the ensemble is playing during this flute line, and commenters could clarify whether, in their experiment, the flute line could still be heard above these other instruments.

Comment: I just now posted the question on the main site: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/94406/is-this-fortissimo-passage-in-the-flute-possible